# collect2: ld returned 1 exit status when compiling through php exec

Tags: php, exec

I am working on a small php-mysql project and working inside /var/www/project on a freshly installed Apache/2.2.22 server(Ubuntu) in Ubuntu 12.04.1

I have chown[ed] the /var/www folder recursively to give ownership to www-data. Inside project i have a php file that tries to execute **exec('gcc sample.c')** but i get an error saying  **collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**.I do not get this error when doing this through terminal.

In addition, an executable a.out placed inside the same folder runs fine when **exec('gcc sample.c')** is replaced by **exec('./a.out')**

How can i fix this? PS:I am a total beginner in this.

php code inside project:

```
<?php
require('connect.php');

$path='sample.c';
chmod($path,0777);
$command= 'gcc sample.c 2>&1';
$method = exec($command);
print_r($method);
?>
```

sample.c code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("SUCCESS\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372897/undefined-reference-to-collect2-ld-returned-1-exit-status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually happens because **not having permission to create *.out* file**. May be when you compile or run it through terminal you will have enough permissions to do so and you might have run from the folder where the c file resided. Please check through the permission. 
Do remember that when you run a php file the user is  *www-data* not root or any other.